# Android - Call onDraw() explicitly

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I have a situation in which I want to draw some values in canvas. These values comes from another activity.

```
 Canvas myCanvas;

public void findSubUnit(String name) {
    unitName = name;
    for (Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> values : subUnits.entrySet()) {

        key = values.getKey();
        if (unitName.equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
            Log.i("prj,match unit=", key);

            v = values.getValue();
            myCanvas = new Canvas();
            onDraw(myCanvas);

        }
    }
```

This is my `onDraw` method.

```
  void onDraw(Canvas canvas, ArrayList<String> units) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawText("hello", 100, 130, paint);
    }
```

It display nothing even not an error. How can I send `arraylist` to `onDraw` explicitly.

Comment: Don't try to call is explicitly.  Just `invalidate()` the view.

Comment: how can i send arrayList to onDraw then?

Comment: What do you mean, `send arrayList to onDraw`?  Please forget the code.  **What** are you trying to do?

Comment: actually i have to display some unit name according to input so it may differ each time when user select the unit like density,volume etc.

Comment: You cannot just create a canvas and expect something to happen on screen.  Every view has a "backing bitmap".  The bitmap is what you see on screen.  A `Canvas` is just a holder for drawing calls which are made to the bitmap.  You don't say why you are not just using a TextView but if you really want a canvas, then create a custom view.  Give it a public method to set the value you want to display.  Call the set method with the value.  The method should then `invalidate` the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make custom view and override all 3 contractor, Put  ArrayList units inside custom  class write setter getter for  ArrayList then call

> requestLayout();

on custom view

invalidate() just causes the views to be redrawn: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

requestLayout() asks that the views go through a new measure/layout pass (and then redraw): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()